# JavaFX - TableView - setItems : The method setItems(ObservableList) in the type TableView is not applicable for the arguments (ObservableList)

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, scenebuilder

I've a problem when I try to set my items into a tableView, for information I use SceneBuilder.

Main.java :

```
public class Main extends Application {
private static Stage theStage;  
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    testDatas();
    launch();
}

public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
    theStage = stage;
    Group acteur = new Group();
    acteur.getChildren().add(
    FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("views/options.fxml")));
    theStage.setTitle("Where's My Money");      
    Scene scene = new Scene(acteur, 1280.0, 720.0);
    theStage.setScene(scene);
    theStage.show();
}

public static void initialize() {
    launch();
}

public static void setScene(Group acteur, String titre) throws IOException {
    Scene scene = new Scene(acteur);

    theStage.setTitle(titre);
    theStage.setScene(scene);
    theStage.show();
}
}
```

views/ControllerOptions.class

```
public class ControllerOptions implements Initializable{

@FXML private TableView<?> TV_currency;
@FXML private TableColumn<Currency, String> TC_name;
@FXML private TableColumn<Currency, Double> TC_value;
private ObservableList<Currency> currencies = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

//FUNCTIONS
@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle rb){
    //initialisation Table Currencies
    for (Currency currency : Datas.getInstance().getCurrencies()) {
        currencies.add(currency);
    }       
    TC_name.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Currency, String>("name"));
    TC_value.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Currency, Double>("value"));
    TV_currency.setItems(currencies); // <= HERE'S THE ERROR
}
}
```

Models/Currency.class

```
public class Currency {

private String name;
private double value;

public Currency(String name, double value) {
    setName(name);
    setValue(value);
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setValue(double value) {
    this.value = value;
}
public double getValue() {
    return value;
}
}
```

I've this error :
**The method setItems(ObservableList) in the type TableView is not applicable for the arguments (ObservableList)**

If you can help me I'll be very gratefull.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is `TV_currency`? It is not defined in the code you posted.

Comment: My bad, I didn't put them here but they're in the source code, I'll edit this. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared the backing data correctly as

```
private ObservableList<Currency> currencies ;
```

but you declared the table using a wildcard:

```
@FXML private TableView<?> TV_currency;
```

Consequently, the types don't match when you try to set the items in the table.

Change the declaration of the table to

```
@FXML private TableView<Currency> TV_currency;
```